# Как скрыть часть текста или весь в TextView?

Tags: java, android, строки, textview, hide

В `TextView` у меня выводится несколько строковых ресурсов:

```
<string name = "one"><![CDATA[ <h2>Большой текст 1</h2><b>текст 1</b> ]]></string>
<string name = "two"><![CDATA[ <h2>Большой текст 2</h2><b>текст 2</b> ]]></string>
```

Я их всех вывожу в один `TextView` путем складывания. Но мне нужно, чтобы они были частично или полностью скрыты и видны только заголовки (`<h2></h2>`), а при нажатии на один из них - текст раскрывался. Какие есть пути решения этой проблемы? Уже многое испробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете html текст.

Сделайте так

Если это `< Android Nougat`

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

И `>= Android Nougat`

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT))`;

Вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: это чтобы работали html теги, а они работают (частично).. вопрос как скрыть текст после заголовка